# UI not updating when sorting observable array in KnockoutJs

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, knockout.js

I am facing problem when i am sorting observable array, array gets updated but not changing UI

**code:**

**Model code:**

```
function OrderByOptionModel(field, displayText, isSelected, dispIndex) {
    var self = this;

    self.field = field;
    self.dispText = displayText;
    self.isSelected = ko.observable(isSelected);
    self.dispIndex = dispIndex;

    self.click = function (data) {
        if (data == null) return;
        data.isSelected(!data.isSelected());
    };

    self.getOrderByOptions = function () {
        return [
            new OrderByOptionModel(OrderByTypes.INDUSTRY, 'Industry', false, 1),
            new OrderByOptionModel(OrderByTypes.SUPERSECTOR, 'Super Sector', false, 2),
            new OrderByOptionModel(OrderByTypes.SECTOR, 'Sector', false, 3),
            new OrderByOptionModel(OrderByTypes.SUBSECTOR, 'Sub Sector', false, 4),
            new OrderByOptionModel(OrderByTypes.COUNTRY, 'Country', false, 5),
            new OrderByOptionModel(OrderByTypes.MARKETCAP, 'Market Cap', false, 6),
            new OrderByOptionModel(OrderByTypes.ATOZ, 'A - Z', false, 7),
            new OrderByOptionModel(OrderByTypes.DATETIME, 'Date Time', false, 8)
        ];
    };
    return self;
}
```

**Observable Array:**

```
self.orderByOptions = ko.observableArray(OrderByOptionModel().getOrderByOptions());
```

**Sorting Code:**

```
 self.orderByOptions().sort(function (l, r) {
             return l.dispIndex > r.dispIndex ? 1 : -1;
        });
```

But UI not gets updated i dont know where is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the parenthesis in your observableArray assignment.

```
self.orderByOptions = ko.observableArray(OrderByOptionModel().getOrderByOptions);
```

The thing with knockout is it calls functions on your behalf when binding things to observables.  Sometimes just removing the parenthesis to functions that return data and binding to the function itself fixes it.

Comment: You don't need to assign it to `ko.observableArray(..)` at all if `self.orderByOptions` is made observable in the beginning. Then all you have to do is `self.orderByOptions(OrderByOptionModel().getOrderByOptions);`.